# not validvalue for the expected return type integer.raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type error

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpY2v.png)

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSumClosest(self, nums, target):
        sum1=0
        t1=target+1
        t2=target-1
        for i in nums:
            if i==t1 or i==t2 or i==target:
                sum1+=i
        print(sum1)
```

IDLE is executing

But LEETCODE is posing the error

> Given an integer array nums of length n and an integer target, find three integers in nums such that the sum is closest to target.

> Return the sum of the three integers.

> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [-1,2,1,-4], target = 1
Output: 2
Explanation: The sum that is closest to the target is 2. (-1 + 2 + 1 = 2).
```

Comment: In idle, you need to do `print(solution.threeSumClosest(...))` to match LeetCode

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to run the provided code the output was 3 instead of 2.

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSumClosest(self, nums, target):
        sum1=0
        t1=target+1
        t2=target-1
        for i in nums:
            if i==t1 or i==t2 or i==target:
                sum1+=i
        return sum1

nums = [-1,2,1,-4]
target = 1
solution = Solution()
result = solution.threeSumClosest(nums, target)
print(result)
```

This is normal because it will enter the if conditions three times